# NPN transistor not emitting anticipated voltage

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, npn, 7segmentdisplay

I have 12 V connected to the collector of an NPN transistor. I have a pin of an ESP8255 (which emits 3.3 V) connected to the base. I'm trying to power a 7-segment display with it, but the emitter voltage is only about 5 to 8 V, so it's not enough to power the display. Why is this happening?

I was under the impression that providing a base voltage basically allowed the voltage from the collector to flow through to the emitter.

Obviously I'm missing something. I'd really appreciate any clarity you can provide.

Comment: You need a resistor between the collector to the 12V, otherwise the power supply is being shorted to ground

Comment: You also need a base resistor.

Comment: @Michael How is it being shorted to ground?

Comment: @winny Why do I need a base resistor? Does the voltage need to be reduced?

Comment: If you apply 5 V to a base of an NPN with emitter connected to ground, you will fry the base or 5 V supply, depending on what gives up first. B-E is basically a diode with about 0.7 V drop. Please simulate your circuit.

Comment: I'm only applying 3.3V to the base.

Comment: with an NPN, you should connect the emitter to gnd, the base to your ESP via a 330ohm resistor, and the collector to your display's V- power input.

Comment: Where does the 12V go?

Comment: Doesn’t matter. You need must have a base resistor. Please simulate your circuit.

Comment: I am simulating the circuit. Why do I need a base resistor?

Comment: you can damage your GPIO if you don't have a base resistor. you can also damage it by feeding it 12v; it's not a high-side switching device like you describe. for that you need a PNP high-side, with a pullup resistor, then another NPN connecting the PNP's base to gnd through the NPN and a resistor, feeding the NPN's base from your GPIO.

Comment: What current do you simulate with 3.3 V with no resistor into base? What does the transistor datasheet say about that current?

Comment: I'm actually just playing with the transistor to see how it works, so no there's nothing else connected. It's a very simple cicuit which I thought was sufficiently described and didn't require a schematic. Others were able to "try", and quite effectively too.

Comment: @All - The discussion was becoming increasingly unfriendly so some comments have been removed (as well as others that are now obsolete). Don't repeat them.

Comment: @namarino41 - Hi, The general topic of the deleted comments was regarding why this question was closed. I expect that it was at least partly due to the lack of a schematic in the question and the fact that the reported voltage measurements don't seem to agree with (at least some guesses of) what people imagine the missing schematic to be. Specifically, with NPN emitter follower, if Vb = 3.3 V then Ve shouldn't be 5 V to 8 V as you reported. So there must be something we're misunderstanding / misinterpreting, notwithstanding the useful info in the answers.

Comment: (continued) Or perhaps the transistor is damaged e.g. due to the lack of a base resistor. || Including a schematic & photos of the measurement setup would have been the first stage in trying to understand that Vb / Ve measurement discrepancy. However since you said "it didn't require a schematic" people couldn't investigate further, which likely caused some frustration. || As you have accepted an answer indicating that you don't need further help and since this isn't the place for long discussions, we'll stop here. Take it to Meta if you want to start a constructive meta discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I was under the impression that providing a base voltage basically allowed the voltage from the collector to flow through to the emitter.*"

No - a voltage cannot "flow".

In a nutshell: A bipolar transistor works like a current source which is controlled by the base-emitter voltage Vbe (which always must be app. in the range 0.6...0.7 volts).

This current (for an NPN device) is directed from the collector to the emitter and is converted to a corresponding output voltage with the help of a resistor - either in the collector path (voltage amplification) or in the emitter path (unity voltage gain due to the negative feedback effect).

When you are required to live with a signal voltage Vo in the order of some volts, you have two alternatives:

- Common collector configuration (emitter follower): The current (some mA) through the emitter resistor Re (some kOhms) creates a voltage Ve which reduces the voltage Vbe to the required/necessary voltage of app. 0.7 volts:
- Common emitter configuration (voltage amplification): When the emitter is grounded (switch application) the base voltage Vb must be reduced to app. 0.6..07 volts using a corresponding voltage divider or a series resistor Rs between the input voltage Vo and the base node (voltage division between Rs and the base-emitter path).

Answer (score 6):

You have the NPN transistor in "Common Collector" configuration, also known as "Emitter Follower" configuration. See [Emitter follower](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74563/emitter-follower)  This configuration gives current gain, but the emitter voltage will be limited to one diode-drop lower than the base voltage. So for 3.3V Vb, and assuming Vbe=0.6V, then Ve would be limited to 2.7V.

For driving LEDs, especially from a higher-voltage source, it's usually better to use a "Common Emitter" configuration, see [Why would one drive LEDs with a common emitter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57845/why-would-one-drive-leds-with-a-common-emitter)